# How do I create a user for my application pool with elevated privileges in Azure?

Tags: c#, azure, model-view-controller, elevated-privileges

I want my mvc web application to be able to create directories and to make this happen there was a suggestion to create a new user in my application pool with elevated privileges.  My web application is hosted on Azure and I wanted to know how I can do this and if it's the correct way to go.

Here is my code in my web application for creating a directory.

```
public ActionResult Async_Save(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files, int? id)
{
    if (files != null)
    {
        string filepath = "/Content/CarData/";
        Directory.CreateDirectory(filepath + id);

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var physicalPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(filepath + id), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(physicalPath);
        }
    }
    return Content("");
}
```

It doesn't work but I don't get an error message either.  From discussions I've had here on stack, the suggestion has been that the application itself doesn't have the permissions to create the directory.  That makes sense, so how I can create the required user and permissions?

Comment: Your premise might be a bit flawed. Why do you want to store files on the web server itself? It's quite rare that this is actually needed (generally, you should use storage accounts instead)

Answer (score 0):

If you're running the Web Application on an Azure Web App the answer's really simple: *you cannot*.

The reason for this is twofold:

1. You're running in a sandbox and they do not want to give anyone elevated privileges
2. Storing information on local disk is not encouraged, since you might lose this information at any point in time (when your app recycles for instance).

You should write data that is to be persisted in [Azure Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/).

Taken from the [Azure runtime environment](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-runtime-environment#file-system) description on GitHub:

> Azure Web Apps run in a sandboxed environment that allows multiple sites to safely co-exist on the same machine.
>
> In most cases, sites are able to do most things that 'normal' web sites typically need to do. But in some scenario, you may run into something that doesn't work due to sandbox limitations. See [Azure Web-App Sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox) for more details.

The most important/relevant piece of information from that last article is here (I trimmed it down a bit):

> **Home directory access (d:\home)**
> Every Azure Web App has a home directory stored/backed by Azure Storage. This network share is where
> applications store their content. This directory is available for the
> sandbox with read/write access.
>
> **Local directory access (d:\local)**
> Every Azure Web App has a local directory which is temporary and is deleted when the app is no
> longer running on the VM. This directory is a place to store temporary
> data for the application.
>
> **System drive access**
> Applications can read the system drive as controlled by ACLs on the drive. *Applications cannot write to any
> location on the system drive, as implemented in the sandbox (i.e. even
> if ACLs allowed writing to a location on system drive, the sandbox
> would restrict it).*